# Calling a block withing a block in ruby without executing the first

Tags: ruby

I am passing a block to a method for delayed execution something like

```
a = Proc.new do 
   puts "call me later"
end
```

Let's say I'm using this for caching expensive calls. Now lets say I wan't part of my code to run now, and part of my code to run later something like this

```
    a = Proc.new do |c|
      puts "call me later"
      c.some_method do
        puts "call me now"
      end
    end
```

Is it possible to get the output of "`call me now`" once you have  the object `a`  without calling the code to output "`call me later`"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but what you have is a Proc that expects an object to be passed as a parameter, and that object has a method that accepts a block.

```
module ModB
  def self.some_method
    puts 'some_method before yield'
    yield
    puts 'some_method after yield'
  end
end

proc_a = Proc.new do |b|
  puts 'proc_a called'
  b.some_method do
    puts 'block called'
  end
end

proc_a.(ModB)
# proc_a called
# some_method before yield
# block called
# some_method after yield
```

So, proc_a either needs a flag of some sort

```
proc_a = Proc.new do |run_me, b|
  puts 'proc_a called' if run_me
  b.some_method do
    puts 'block called'
  end
end
```

Or, you should be storing the block for some_method separately.

```
proc_a = Proc.new do
  puts 'proc_a called'
end

proc_b = Proc.new do
  puts 'block called'
end

proc_a.()
# proc_a called

ModB.some_method(&proc_b)
#   some_method before yield
#   block called
#   some_method after yield
```